# How to make sphinx document via pdflatex \raggedright?

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, pdflatex

How can I render reST document with `\raggedright` command applied to all the text if I use `pdflatex`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom template.

In the following example, I'll be using `xelatex`. I would copy the default template for xelatex from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/writers/latex2e/xelatex.tex` to a file called `mytemplate.tex`

The default template looks like this:

```
$head_prefix% generated by Docutils <http://docutils.sourceforge.net/>
% rubber: set program xelatex
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
$requirements
%%% Custom LaTeX preamble
$latex_preamble
%%% User specified packages and stylesheets
$stylesheet
%%% Fallback definitions for Docutils-specific commands
$fallbacks$pdfsetup
$titledata
%%% Body
\begin{document}
$body_pre_docinfo$docinfo$dedication$abstract$body
\end{document}
```

You could add `\raggedright` just after `\begin{document}`.

For rendering the document, I'd use the following commands:

```
rst2xetex --template=mytemplate.tex --use-latex-docinfo mydoc.rst
xelatex mydoc.tex
xelatex mydoc.tex
rm -f *.out *.aux *.log mydoc.tex
```

(This is on a UNIX-like operating system.)

Comment: Your answer made me curious about template for `pdflatex`. Long story short: I ended up in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/writers/latex.py` and found `default_elemets`. One member is `maketitle` and I have modified it to contain '\\maketitle \\raggedright' in my `conf.py` file. I mark your answer correct, even it is for `xetex`, since you kicked me in the right direction.